# Uglify breaking progressive nested object creation

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify

I'm progressively creating nested objects.  The original code works, but the uglified code does not.

**Working Original Code**

```js
function(type, id, fieldName) {
  if (!this.model.proposed_changes)
    this.model.proposed_changes = {};
  if (!this.model.proposed_changes[type])
    this.model.proposed_changes[type] = {};
  if (!this.model.proposed_changes[type][id])
    this.model.proposed_changes[type][id] = {};
  if (fieldName) {
    this.model.proposed_changes[type][id][fieldName] = this.model.proposed_changes[type][id][fieldName] || {};
  }
}
```

**Uglified Code** (newlines added for readability)

```js
function(e, i, n) {
  this.model.proposed_changes || (this.model.proposed_changes = {}),
    this.model.proposed_changes[e] || (this.model.proposed_changes[e] = {}),
    this.model.proposed_changes[e][i] || (this.model.proposed_changes[e][i] = {}),
    n && (this.model.proposed_changes[e][i][n] = this.model.proposed_changes[e][i][n] || {})
}
```

This uglified function errors out when `this.model.proposed_changes` is `undefined` saying `Cannot read property <ID passed in> of undefined`.  I'm not sure why the uglified code doesn't work, but it seems as though the assignments aren't run sequentially, even though they should be (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b37css7(v=vs.94).aspx)

I'm using gulp-uglify with other configuration other than keeping licenses in tact, though I have tried this with `mangle: false` with no effect.

Is there some way to force uglify to ensure that assignments happen in order, assuming that's the problem?

**Background**

In my example, I'm guaranteed that this.model exists, but not that it has a sub-object called proposed_changes.  This pattern continues until I have this.model.proposed_changes[type][id][fieldName].  If there's a better way to do this, I'd certainly be interested.

Comment: commands are always executed sequentially in JS. And the uglified code should work exactly as the original. Have you tried to replace the uglified function with the original? Does it one also fail, or not? You say, `this.model` is guaranteed to exist, but did you actually check it?

Comment: Your advice helped me find the issue, so thanks!  The backend was incorrectly initializing this.model.proposed_changes to `'{}'` instead of `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

The production backend was incorrectly initializing this.model.proposed_changes to `'{}'` instead of `{}`.  Once that bug was fixed the code worked as expected.